# code file size increase error in blackberry

Tags: blackberry

I am saving 2500 name in array .But I am getting error code increase the size .So it is not run ..Can you please tell me how to solve that error ?  I only show few element due to restriction .

package mypackage;

```
public class GlobalList {

    public static String[] stationList={
             "Abbey Wood  - (ABW)",
             "Aber - (ABE)",
             "Abercynon - (ACY)",
             "Aberdare - (ABA)",

             "Barry Island - (BYI)",
             "Barry Links - (BYL)",
             "Barton-on-Humber - (BAU)",
             "Basildon - (BSO)",
             "Basingstoke - (BSK)",


             "Glasgow Central - (GLC)",
             "Glasgow Queen Street - (GLQ)",
             "Glasshoughton - (GLH)",
             "Glazebrook - (GLZ)",
             "Gleneagles - (GLE)",
             "Glenfinnan - (GLF)",
             "Glengarnock - (GLG)",
             "Glenrothes with Thornton - (GLT)",
             "Glossop - (GLO)",
             "Gloucester - (GCR)",
             "Glynde - (GLY)",
             "Gobowen - (GOB)",
             "Godalming - (GOD)",
             "Godley - (GDL)",
             "Godstone - (GDN)",
             "Goldthorpe - (GOE)",


             "Kirkcaldy - (KDY)",
             "Kirkconnel - (KRK)",
             "Kirkdale - (KKD)",
             "Kirkham & Wesham - (KKM)",
             "Kirkhill - (KKH)",
             "Kirknewton - (KKN)",
             "Kirkwood - (KWD)",
             "Kirton Lindsey - (KTL)",
             "Kiveton Bridge - (KIV)",
             "Kiveton Park - (KVP)",
             "Knaresborough - (KNA)",
             "Knebworth - (KBW)",
             "Knighton - (KNI)",
             "Knockholt - (KCK)",
             "Knottingley - (KNO)",
             "Knucklas - (KNU)",
             "Knutsford - (KNF)",
             "Kyle of Lochalsh - (KYL)",
             "Ladybank - (LDY)",
             "Ladywell - (LAD)",
             "Laindon - (LAI)",
             "Lairg - (LRG)",
             "Lake - (LKE)",
             "Lakenheath - (LAK)",
             "Lamphey - (LAM)",
             "Lanark - (LNK)",
             "Lancaster - (LAN)",
             "Lancing - (LAC)",
             "Landywood - (LAW)",
             "Langbank - (LGB)",
             "Langho - (LHO)",
             "Langley (Berks) - (LNY)",
             "Langley Green - (LGG)",
             "Langley Mill - (LGM)",
             "Langside - (LGS)",
             "Langwathby - (LGW)",
             "Langwith-Whaley Thorns - (LAG)",
             "Lapford - (LAP)",
             "Lapworth - (LPW)",
             "Larbert - (LBT)",
             "Largs - (LAR)",
             "Larkhall - (LRH)",
             "Laurencekirk - (LAU)",
             "Lawrence Hill - (LWH)",
             "Layton (Lancs) - (LAY)",
             "Lazonby & Kirkoswald - (LZB)",
             "Lea Green - (LEG)",
             "Lea Hall - (LEH)",
             "Leagrave - (LEA)",
             "Lealholm - (LHM)",
             "Leamington Spa - (LMS)",
             "Leasowe - (LSW)",
             "Leatherhead - (LHD)",
             "Ledbury - (LED)",
             "Lee (London) - (LEE)",
             "Leeds - (LDS)",
             "Leicester - (LEI)",
             "Leigh (Kent) - (LIH)",
             "Leigh-on-Sea - (LES)",
             "Leighton Buzzard - (LBZ)",
             "Lelant - (LEL)",
             "Lelant Saltings - (LTS)",
             "Lenham - (LEN)",
             "Lenzie - (LNZ)",
             "Leominster - (LEO)",
             "Letchworth Garden City - (LET)",
             "Leuchars (for St. Andrews) - (LEU)",
             "Levenshulme - (LVM)",
             "Lewes - (LWS)",
             "Lewisham - (LEW)",
             "Leyland - (LEY)",
             "Leyton Midland Road - (LEM)",
             "Leytonstone High Road - (LER)",
             "Lichfield City - (LIC)",
             "Lichfield Trent Valley - (LTV)",
             "Lidlington - (LID)",
             "Limehouse - (LHS)",
             "Lincoln Central - (LCN)",
             "Lingfield - (LFD)",
             "Lingwood - (LGD)",
             "Linlithgow - (LIN)",
             "Liphook - (LIP)",
             "Liskeard - (LSK)",
             "Liss - (LIS)",
             "Lisvane & Thornhill - (LVT)",
             "Little Kimble - (LTK)",
             "Little Sutton - (LTT)",
             "Littleborough - (LTL)",
             "Littlehampton - (LIT)",
             "Littlehaven - (LVN)",
             "Littleport - (LTP)",
             "Liverpool Central - (LVC)",
             "Liverpool James Street - (LVJ)",
             "Liverpool Lime Street - (LIV)",
             "Liverpool South Parkway - (LPY)",
             "Livingston North - (LSN)",
             "Livingston South - (LVG)",
             "Llanaber - (LLA)",
             "Llanbedr - (LBR)",
             "Llanbister Road - (LLT)",
             "Llanbradach - (LNB)",
             "Llandaf - (LLN)",
             "Llandanwg - (LDN)",
             "Llandecwyn - (LLC)",
             "Llandeilo - (LLL)",
             "Llandovery - (LLV)",
             "Llandrindod - (LLO)",
             "Llandudno - (LLD)",
             "Llandudno Junction - (LLJ)",
             "Llandybie - (LLI)",
             "Llanelli - (LLE)",
             "Llanfairfechan - (LLF)",
             "Llanfairpwll - (LPG)",
             "Llangadog - (LLG)",
             "Llangammarch - (LLM)",
             "Llangennech - (LLH)",
             "Llangynllo - (LGO)",
             "Llanharan - (LLR)",
             "Llanhilleth - (LTH)",
             "Llanishen - (LLS)",
             "Llanrwst - (LWR)",
             "Llansamlet - (LAS)",
             "Llantwit Major - (LWM)",
             "Llanwrda - (LNR)",
             "Llanwrtyd - (LNW)",
             "Llwyngwril - (LLW)",
             "Llwynypia - (LLY)",
             "Loch Awe - (LHA)",
             "Loch Eil Outward Bound - (LHE)",
             "Lochailort - (LCL)",
             "Locheilside - (LCS)",
             "Lochgelly - (LCG)",
             "Lochluichart - (LCC)",
             "Lochwinnoch - (LHW)",
             "Lockerbie - (LOC)",
             "Lockwood - (LCK)",
             "London Blackfriars - (BFR)",
             "London Bridge - (LBG)",
             "London Cannon Street - (CST)",
             "London Charing Cross - (CHX)",
             "London Euston - (EUS)",
             "London Fenchurch Street - (FST)",
             "London Fields - (LOF)",
             "London Kings Cross - (KGX)",
             "London Liverpool Street - (LST)",
             "London Marylebone - (MYB)",
             "London Paddington - (PAD)",
             "London Road (Brighton) - (LRB)",
             "London Road (Guildford) - (LRD)",
             "London St Pancras International - (STP)",
             "London St Pancras (Intl) - (SPX)",
             "London Victoria - (VIC)",
             "London Waterloo - (WAT)",
             "London Waterloo East - (WAE)",
             "Long Buckby - (LBK)",
             "Long Eaton - (LGE)",
             "Long Preston - (LPR)",
             "Longbeck - (LGK)",
             "Longbridge - (LOB)",
             "Longcross - (LNG)",
             "Longfield - (LGF)",
             "Longniddry - (LND)",
             "Longport - (LPT)",
             "Longton - (LGN)",
             "Looe - (LOO)",
             "Lostock - (LOT)",
             "Lostock Gralam - (LTG)",
             "Lostock Hall - (LOH)",
             "Lostwithiel - (LOS)",
             "Loughborough - (LBO)",
             "Loughborough Junction - (LGJ)",
             "Lowdham - (LOW)",
             "Lower Sydenham - (LSY)",
             "Lowestoft - (LWT)",
             "Ludlow - (LUD)",
             "Luton - (LUT)",
             "Luton Airport Parkway - (LTN)",
             "Luxulyan - (LUX)",
             "Lydney - (LYD)",
             "Lye (West Midlands) - (LYE)",
             "Lymington Pier - (LYP)",
             "Lymington Town - (LYT)",
             "Lympstone Commando - (LYC)",
             "Lympstone Village - (LYM)",
             "Lytham - (LTM)",
             "Macclesfield - (MAC)",
             "Machynlleth - (MCN)",
             "Maesteg - (MST)",
             "Maesteg (Ewenny Road) - (MEW)",
             "Maghull - (MAG)",
             "Maiden Newton - (MDN)",
             "Maidenhead - (MAI)",
             "Maidstone Barracks - (MDB)",
             "Maidstone East - (MDE)",
             "Maidstone West - (MDW)",
             "Malden Manor - (MAL)",
             "Mallaig - (MLG)",
             "Malton - (MLT)",
             "Malvern Link - (MVL)",
             "Manchester Airport - (MIA)",
             "Manchester Oxford Road - (MCO)",
             "Manchester Piccadilly - (MAN)",
             "Manchester Utd Football Gd - (MUF)",
             "Manchester Victoria - (MCV)",
             "Manea - (MNE)",
             "Manningtree - (MNG)",
             "Manor Park - (MNP)",
             "Manor Road - (MNR)",
             "Manorbier - (MRB)",
             "Manors - (MAS)",
             "Mansfield - (MFT)",
             "Mansfield Woodhouse - (MSW)",
             "March - (MCH)",
             "Marden (Kent) - (MRN)",
             "Margate - (MAR)",
             "Market Harborough - (MHR)",
             "Market Rasen - (MKR)",
             "Markinch - (MNC)",
             "Marks Tey - (MKT)",
             "Marlow - (MLW)",
             "Marple - (MPL)",
             "Marsden (Yorks) - (MSN)",
             "Marske - (MSK)",
             "Marston Green - (MGN)",
             "Martin Mill - (MTM)",
             "Martins Heron - (MAO)",
             "Marton - (MTO)",
             "Maryhill - (MYH)",
             "Maryland - (MYL)",
             "Maryport - (MRY)",
             "Matlock - (MAT)",
             "Matlock Bath - (MTB)",
             "Mauldeth Road - (MAU)",
             "Maxwell Park - (MAX)",
             "Maybole - (MAY)",
             "Maze Hill - (MZH)",
             "Meadowhall - (MHS)",
             "Meldreth - (MEL)",
             "Melksham - (MKM)",
             "Melton Mowbray - (MMO)",
             "Melton (Suffolk) - (MES)",
             "Menheniot - (MEN)",
             "Menston - (MNN)",
             "Meols - (MEO)",
             "Meols Cop - (MEC)",
             "Meopham - (MEP)",
             "Merryton - (MEY)",
             "Merstham - (MHM)",
             "Merthyr Tydfil - (MER)",
             "Merthyr Vale - (MEV)",
             "Metheringham - (MGM)",
             "MetroCentre - (MCE)",
             "Mexborough - (MEX)",
             "Micheldever - (MIC)",
             "Micklefield - (MIK)",
             "Middlesbrough - (MBR)",
             "Middlewood - (MDL)",
             "Midgham - (MDG)",
             "Milford Haven - (MFH)",
             "Milford (Surrey) - (MLF)",
             "Mill Hill Broadway - (MIL)",
             "Mill Hill (Lancs) - (MLH)",
             "Millbrook (Beds) - (MLB)",
             "Millbrook (Hants) - (MBK)",
             "Milliken Park - (MIN)",
             "Millom - (MLM)",
             "Mills Hill (Manchester) - (MIH)",
             "Milngavie - (MLN)",
             "Milton Keynes Central - (MKC)",
             "Minffordd - (MFF)",
             "Minster - (MSR)",
             "Mirfield - (MIR)",
             "Mistley - (MIS)",
             "Mitcham Eastfields - (MTC)",
             "Mitcham Junction - (MIJ)",
             "Mobberley - (MOB)",
             "Monifieth - (MON)",
             "Monks Risborough - (MRS)",
             "Montpelier - (MTP)",
             "Montrose - (MTS)",
             "Moorfields - (MRF)",
             "Moorgate - (MOG)",
             "Moorside - (MSD)",
             "Moorthorpe - (MRP)",
             "Morar - (MRR)",
             "Morchard Road - (MRD)",
             "Morden South - (MDS)",
             "Morecambe - (MCM)",
             "Moreton (Dorset) - (MTN)",
             "Moreton (Merseyside) - (MRT)",
             "Moreton-in-Marsh - (MIM)",
             "Morfa Mawddach - (MFA)",
             "Morley - (MLY)",
             "Morpeth - (MPT)",
             "Mortimer - (MOR)",
             "Mortlake - (MTL)",
             "Moses Gate - (MSS)",
             "Moss Side - (MOS)",
             "Mossley Hill - (MSH)",
             "Mossley (Manchester) - (MSL)",
             "Mosspark - (MPK)",
             "Moston - (MSO)",
             "Motherwell - (MTH)",
             "Motspur Park - (MOT)",
             "Mottingham - (MTG)",
             "Mottisfont & Dunbridge - (DBG)",
             "Mouldsworth - (MLD)",
             "Moulsecoomb - (MCB)",
             "Mount Florida - (MFL)",
             "Mount Vernon - (MTV)",
             "Mountain Ash - (MTA)",
             "Muir of Ord - (MOO)",
             "Muirend - (MUI)",
             "Musselburgh - (MUB)",
             "Mytholmroyd - (MYT)",
             "Nafferton - (NFN)",
             "Nailsea & Backwell - (NLS)",
             "Nairn - (NRN)",
             "Nantwich - (NAN)",
             "Narberth - (NAR)",
             "Narborough - (NBR)",
             "Navigation Road - (NVR)",
             "Neath - (NTH)",
             "Needham Market - (NMT)",
             "Neilston - (NEI)",
             "Nelson - (NEL)",
             "Neston - (NES)",
             "Netherfield - (NET)",
             "Nethertown - (NRT)",
             "Netley - (NTL)",
             "New Barnet - (NBA)",
             "New Beckenham - (NBC)",
             "New Brighton - (NBN)",
             "New Clee - (NCE)",
             "New Cross - (NWX)",
             "New Cross Gate - (NXG)",
             "New Cumnock - (NCK)",
             "New Eltham - (NEH)",
             "New Holland - (NHL)",
             "New Hythe - (NHE)",
             "New Lane - (NLN)",
             "New Malden - (NEM)",
             "New Mills Central - (NMC)",
             "New Mills Newtown - (NMN)",
             "New Milton - (NWM)",
             "New Pudsey - (NPD)",
             "New Southgate - (NSG)",
             "Newark Castle - (NCT)",
             "Newark North Gate - (NNG)",
             "Newbridge - (NBE)",
             "Newbury - (NBY)",
             "Newbury Racecourse - (NRC)",
             "Newcastle - (NCL)",
             "Newcraighall - (NEW)",
             "Newhaven Harbour - (NVH)",
             "Newhaven Town - (NVN)",
             "Newington - (NGT)",
             "Newmarket - (NMK)",
             "Newport (Essex) - (NWE)",
             "Newport (South Wales) - (NWP)",
             "Newquay - (NQY)",
             "Newstead - (NSD)",
             "Newton Abbot - (NTA)",
             "Newton Aycliffe - (NAY)",
             "Newton for Hyde - (NWN)",
             "Newton (Lanark) - (NTN)",
             "Newton St Cyres - (NTC)",
             "Newton-le-Willows - (NLW)",
             "Newtonmore - (NWR)",
             "Newton-on-Ayr - (NOA)",
             "Newtown (Powys) - (NWT)",
             "Ninian Park - (NNP)",
             "Nitshill - (NIT)",
             "Norbiton - (NBT)",
             "Norbury - (NRB)",
             "Normans Bay - (NSB)",
             "Normanton - (NOR)",
             "North Berwick - (NBW)",
             "North Camp - (NCM)",
             "North Dulwich - (NDL)",
             "North Fambridge - (NFA)",
             "North Llanrwst - (NLR)",
             "North Queensferry - (NQU)",
             "North Road (Darlington) - (NRD)",
             "North Sheen - (NSH)",
             "North Walsham - (NWA)",
             "North Wembley - (NWB)",
             "Northallerton - (NTR)",
             "Northampton - (NMP)",
             "Northfield - (NFD)",
             "Northfleet - (NFL)",
             "Northolt Park - (NLT)",
             "Northumberland Park - (NUM)",
             "Northwich - (NWI)",
             "Norton Bridge - (NTB)",
             "Norwich - (NRW)",
             "Norwood Junction - (NWD)",
             "Nottingham - (NOT)",
             "Nuneaton - (NUN)",
             "Nunhead - (NHD)",
             "Nunthorpe - (NNT)",
             "Nutbourne - (NUT)",
             "Nutfield - (NUF)",
             "Oakengates - (OKN)",
             "Oakham - (OKM)",
             "Oakleigh Park - (OKL)",
             "Oban - (OBN)",
             "Ockendon - (OCK)",
             "Ockley - (OLY)",
             "Okehampton - (OKE)",
             "Old Hill - (OHL)",
             "Old Roan - (ORN)",
             "Old Street - (OLD)",
             "Oldfield Park - (OLF)",
             "Olton - (OLT)",
             "Ore - (ORE)",
             "Ormskirk - (OMS)",
             "Orpington - (ORP)",
             "Orrell - (ORR)",
             "Orrell Park - (OPK)",
             "Otford - (OTF)",
             "Oulton Broad North - (OUN)",
             "Oulton Broad South - (OUS)",
             "Outwood - (OUT)",
             "Overpool - (OVE)",
             "Overton - (OVR)",
             "Oxenholme Lake District - (OXN)",
             "Oxford - (OXF)",
             "Oxshott - (OXS)",
             "Oxted - (OXT)",
             "Paddock Wood - (PDW)",
             "Padgate - (PDG)",
             "Paignton - (PGN)",
             "Paisley Canal - (PCN)",
             "Paisley Gilmour Street - (PYG)",
             "Paisley St James - (PYJ)",
             "Palmers Green - (PAL)",
             "Pangbourne - (PAN)",
             "Pannal - (PNL)",
             "Pantyffynnon - (PTF)",
             "Par - (PAR)",
             "Parbold - (PBL)",
             "Park Street - (PKT)",
             "Parkstone (Dorset) - (PKS)",
             "Parson Street - (PSN)",
             "Partick - (PTK)",
             "Parton - (PRN)",
             "Patchway - (PWY)",
             "Patricroft - (PAT)",
             "Patterton - (PTT)",
             "Peartree - (PEA)",
             "Peckham Rye - (PMR)",
             "Pegswood - (PEG)",
             "Pemberton - (PEM)",
             "Pembrey & Burry Port - (PBY)",
             "Pembroke - (PMB)",
             "Pembroke Dock - (PMD)",
             "Penally - (PNA)",
             "Penarth - (PEN)",
             "Pencoed - (PCD)",
             "Pengam - (PGM)",
             "Penge East - (PNE)",
             "Penge West - (PNW)",
             "Penhelig - (PHG)",
             "Penistone - (PNS)",
             "Penkridge - (PKG)",
             "Penmaenmawr - (PMW)",
             "Penmere - (PNM)",
             "Penrhiwceiber - (PER)",
             "Penrhyndeudraeth - (PRH)",
             "Penrith (North Lakes) - (PNR)",
             "Penryn (Cornwall) - (PYN)",
             "Pensarn (Gwynedd) - (PES)",
             "Penshurst - (PHR)",
             "Pentre-Bach - (PTB)",
             "Pen-y-Bont - (PNY)",
             "Penychain - (PNC)",
             "Penyffordd - (PNF)",
             "Penzance - (PNZ)",
             "Perranwell - (PRW)",
             "Perry Barr - (PRY)",
             "Pershore - (PSH)",
             "Perth - (PTH)",
             "Peterborough - (PBO)",
             "Petersfield - (PTR)",
             "Petts Wood - (PET)",
             "Pevensey & Westham - (PEV)",
             "Pevensey Bay - (PEB)",
             "Pewsey - (PEW)",
             "Pilning - (PIL)",
             "Pinhoe - (PIN)",
             "Pitlochry - (PIT)",
             "Pitsea - (PSE)",
             "Pleasington - (PLS)",
             "Plockton - (PLK)",
             "Pluckley - (PLC)",
             "Plumley - (PLM)",
             "Plumpton - (PMP)",
             "Plumstead - (PLU)",
             "Plymouth - (PLY)",
             "Pokesdown - (POK)",
             "Polegate - (PLG)",
             "Polesworth - (PSW)",
             "Pollokshaws East - (PWE)",
             "Pollokshaws West - (PWW)",
             "Pollokshields East - (PLE)",
             "Pollokshields West - (PLW)",
             "Polmont - (PMT)",
             "Polsloe Bridge - (POL)",
             "Ponders End - (PON)",
             "Pontarddulais - (PTD)",
             "Pontefract Baghill - (PFR)",
             "Pontefract Monkhill - (PFM)",
             "Pontefract Tanshelf - (POT)",
             "Pontlottyn - (PLT)",
             "Pontyclun - (PYC)",
             "Pont-y-Pant - (PYP)",
             "Pontypool & New Inn - (PPL)",
             "Pontypridd - (PPD)",
             "Poole - (POO)",
             "Poppleton - (POP)",
             "Port Glasgow - (PTG)",
             "Port Sunlight - (PSL)",
             "Port Talbot Parkway - (PTA)",
             "Portchester - (PTC)",
             "Porth - (POR)",
             "Porthmadog - (PTM)",
             "Portlethen - (PLN)",
             "Portslade - (PLD)",
             "Portsmouth & Southsea - (PMS)",
             "Portsmouth Arms - (PMA)",
             "Portsmouth Harbour - (PMH)",
             "Possilpark & Parkhouse - (PPK)",
             "Potters Bar - (PBR)",
             "Poulton-le-Fylde - (PFY)",
             "Poynton - (PYT)",
             "Prees - (PRS)",
             "Prescot - (PSC)",
             "Prestatyn - (PRT)",
             "Prestbury - (PRB)",
             "Preston (Lancs) - (PRE)",
             "Preston Park - (PRP)",
             "Prestonpans - (PST)",
             "Prestwick International Airport - (PRA)",
             "Prestwick Town - (PTW)",
             "Priesthill & Darnley - (PTL)",
             "Princes Risborough - (PRR)",
             "Prittlewell - (PRL)",
             "Prudhoe - (PRU)",
             "Pulborough - (PUL)",
             "Purfleet - (PFL)",
             "Purley - (PUR)",
             "Purley Oaks - (PUO)",
             "Putney - (PUT)",
             "Pwllheli - (PWL)",
             "Pyle - (PYL)",
             "Quakers Yard - (QYD)",
             "Queenborough - (QBR)",
             "Queens Park (Glasgow) - (QPK)",
             "Queens Park (London) - (QPW)",
             "Queens Road (Peckham) - (QRP)",
             "Queenstown Road (Battersea) - (QRB)",
             "Quintrell Downs - (QUI)",
             "Radcliffe-on-Trent - (RDF)",
             "Radlett - (RDT)",
             "Radley - (RAD)",
             "Radyr - (RDR)",
             "Rainford - (RNF)",
             "Rainham (Essex) - (RNM)",
             "Rainham (Kent) - (RAI)",
             "Rainhill - (RNH)",
             "Ramsgate - (RAM)",
             "Ramsgreave & Wilpshire - (RGW)",
             "Rannoch - (RAN)",
             "Rauceby - (RAU)",
             "Ravenglass for Eskdale - (RAV)",
             "Ravensbourne - (RVB)",
             "Ravensthorpe - (RVN)",
             "Rawcliffe - (RWC)",
             "Rayleigh - (RLG)",
             "Raynes Park - (RAY)",
             "Reading - (RDG)",
             "Reading West - (RDW)",
             "Rectory Road - (REC)",
             "Redbridge - (RDB)",
             "Redcar Central - (RCC)",
             "Redcar East - (RCE)",
             "Reddish North - (RDN)",
             "Reddish South - (RDS)",
             "Redditch - (RDC)",
             "Redhill - (RDH)",
             "Redland - (RDA)",
             "Redruth - (RED)",
             "Reedham (Norfolk) - (REE)",
             "Reedham (Surrey) - (RHM)",
             "Reigate - (REI)",
             "Renton - (RTN)",
             "Retford - (RET)",
             "Rhiwbina - (RHI)",
             "Rhoose Cardiff International Airport - (RIA)",
             "Rhosneigr - (RHO)",
             "Rhyl - (RHL)",
             "Rhymney - (RHY)",
             "Ribblehead - (RHD)",
             "Rice Lane - (RIL)",
             "Richmond (London) - (RMD)",
             "Rickmansworth - (RIC)",
             "Riddlesdown - (RDD)",
             "Ridgmont - (RID)",
             "Riding Mill - (RDM)",
             "Risca & Pontymister - (RCA)",
             "Rishton - (RIS)",
             "Robertsbridge - (RBR)",
             "Roby - (ROB)",
             "Rochdale - (RCD)",
             "Roche - (ROC)",
             "Rochester - (RTR)",
             "Rochford - (RFD)",
             "Rock Ferry - (RFY)",
             "Rogart - (ROG)",
             "Rogerstone - (ROR)",
             "Rolleston - (ROL)",
             "Roman Bridge - (RMB)",
             "Romford - (RMF)",
             "Romiley - (RML)",
             "Romsey - (ROM)",
             "Roose - (ROO)",
             "Rose Grove - (RSG)",
             "Rose Hill Marple - (RSH)",
             "Rosyth - (ROS)",
             "Rotherham Central - (RMC)",
             "Rotherhithe - (ROE)",
             "Roughton Road - (RNR)",
             "Rowlands Castle - (RLN)",
             "Rowley Regis - (ROW)",
             "Roy Bridge - (RYB)",
             "Roydon - (RYN)",
             "Royston - (RYS)",
             "Ruabon - (RUA)",
             "Rufford - (RUF)",
             "Rugby - (RUG)",
             "Rugeley Town - (RGT)",
             "Rugeley Trent Valley - (RGL)",
             "Runcorn - (RUN)",
             "Runcorn East - (RUE)",
             "Ruskington - (RKT)",
             "Ruswarp - (RUS)",
             "Rutherglen - (RUT)",
             "Ryde St Johns Road - (RYR)",
             "Ryde Esplanade - (RYD)",
             "Ryde Pier Head - (RYP)",
             "Ryder Brow - (RRB)",
             "Rye House - (RYH)",
             "Rye (Sussex) - (RYE)",
             "Salford Central - (SFD)",
             "Salford Crescent - (SLD)",
             "Salfords (Surrey) - (SAF)",
             "Salhouse - (SAH)",
             "Salisbury - (SAL)",
             "Saltaire - (SAE)",
             "Saltash - (STS)",
             "Saltburn - (SLB)",
             "Saltcoats - (SLT)",
             "Saltmarshe - (SAM)",
             "Salwick - (SLW)",
             "Sampford Courtenay - (SMC)",
             "Sandal & Agbrigg - (SNA)",
             "Sandbach - (SDB)",
             "Sanderstead - (SNR)",
             "Sandhills - (SDL)",
             "Sandhurst (Berks) - (SND)",
             "Sandling - (SDG)",
             "Sandown - (SAN)",
             "Sandplace - (SDP)",
             "Sandwell & Dudley - (SAD)",
             "Sandwich - (SDW)",
             "Sandy - (SDY)",
             "Sankey for Penketh - (SNK)",
             "Sanquhar - (SQH)",
             "Sarn - (SRR)",
             "Saundersfoot - (SDF)",
             "Saunderton - (SDR)",
             "Sawbridgeworth - (SAW)",
             "Saxilby - (SXY)",
             "Saxmundham - (SAX)",
             "Scarborough - (SCA)",
             "Scotscalder - (SCT)",
             "Scotstounhill - (SCH)",
             "Scunthorpe - (SCU)",
             "Sea Mills - (SML)",
             "Seaford (Sussex) - (SEF)",
             "Seaforth & Litherland - (SFL)",
             "Seaham - (SEA)",
             "Seamer - (SEM)",
             "Seascale - (SSC)",
             "Seaton Carew - (SEC)",
             "Seer Green & Jordans - (SRG)",
             "Selby - (SBY)",
             "Selhurst - (SRS)",
             "Sellafield - (SEL)",
             "Selling - (SEG)",
             "Selly Oak - (SLY)",
             "Settle - (SET)",
             "Seven Kings - (SVK)",
             "Seven Sisters - (SVS)",
             "Sevenoaks - (SEV)",
             "Severn Beach - (SVB)",
             "Severn Tunnel Junction - (STJ)",
             "Shadwell - (SDE)",
             "Shalford (Surrey) - (SFR)",
             "Shanklin - (SHN)",
             "Shawford - (SHW)",
             "Shawlands - (SHL)",
             "Sheerness-on-Sea - (SSS)",
             "Sheffield - (SHF)",
             "Shelford (Cambs) - (SED)",
             "Shenfield - (SNF)",
             "Shenstone - (SEN)",
             "Shepherd's Bush - (SPB)",
             "Shepherds Well - (SPH)",
             "Shepley - (SPY)",
             "Shepperton - (SHP)",
             "Shepreth - (STH)",
             "Sherborne - (SHE)",
             "Sherburn-in-Elmet - (SIE)",
             "Sheringham - (SHM)",
             "Shettleston - (SLS)",
             "Shieldmuir - (SDM)",
             "Shifnal - (SFN)",
             "Shildon - (SHD)",
             "Shiplake - (SHI)",
             "Shipley (Yorks) - (SHY)",
             "Shippea Hill - (SPP)",
             "Shipton - (SIP)",
             "Shirebrook - (SHB)",
             "Shirehampton - (SHH)",
             "Shireoaks - (SRO)",
             "Shirley - (SRL)",
             "Shoeburyness - (SRY)",
             "Sholing - (SHO)",
             "Shoreditch High Street - (SDC)",
             "Shoreham (Kent) - (SEH)",
             "Shoreham-by-Sea - (SSE)",
             "Shortlands - (SRT)",
             "Shotton - (SHT)",
             "Shotts - (SHS)",
             "Shrewsbury - (SHR)",
             "Sidcup - (SID)",
             "Sileby - (SIL)",
             "Silecroft - (SIC)",
             "Silkstone Common - (SLK)",
             "Silver Street - (SLV)",
             "Silverdale - (SVR)",
             "Singer - (SIN)",
             "Sittingbourne - (SIT)",
             "Skegness - (SKG)",
             "Skewen - (SKE)",
             "Skipton - (SKI)",
             "Slade Green - (SGR)",
             "Slaithwaite - (SWT)",
             "Slateford - (SLA)",
             "Sleaford - (SLR)",
             "Sleights - (SLH)",
             "Slough - (SLO)",
             "Small Heath - (SMA)",
             "Smallbrook Junction - (SAB)",
             "Smethwick Galton Bridge - (SGB)",
             "Smethwick Rolfe Street - (SMR)",
             "Smitham - (SMI)",
             "Smithy Bridge - (SMB)",
             "Snaith - (SNI)",
             "Snodland - (SDA)",
             "Snowdown - (SWO)",
             "Sole Street - (SOR)",
             "Solihull - (SOL)",
             "Somerleyton - (SYT)",
             "South Acton - (SAT)",
             "South Bank - (SBK)",
             "South Bermondsey - (SBM)",
             "South Croydon - (SCY)",
             "South Elmsall - (SES)",
             "South Greenford - (SGN)",
             "South Gyle - (SGL)",
             "South Hampstead - (SOH)",
             "South Kenton - (SOK)",
             "South Merton - (SMO)",
             "South Milford - (SOM)",
             "South Ruislip - (SRU)",
             "South Tottenham - (STO)",
             "South Wigston - (SWS)",
             "South Woodham Ferrers - (SOF)",
             "Southall - (STL)",
             "Southampton Airport Parkway - (SOA)",
             "Southampton Central - (SOU)",
             "Southbourne - (SOB)",
             "Southbury - (SBU)",
             "Southease - (SEE)",
             "Southend Airport - (SIA)",
             "Southend Central - (SOC)",
             "Southend East - (SOE)",
             "Southend Victoria - (SOV)",
             "Southminster - (SMN)",
             "Southport - (SOP)",
             "Southwick - (SWK)",
             "Sowerby Bridge - (SOW)",
             "Spalding - (SPA)",
             "Spean Bridge - (SBR)",
             "Spital - (SPI)",
             "Spondon - (SPO)",
             "Spooner Row - (SPN)",
             "Spring Road - (SRI)",
             "Springburn - (SPR)",
             "Springfield - (SPF)",
             "Squires Gate - (SQU)",
             "St Albans - (SAC)",
             "St Albans Abbey - (SAA)",
             "St Andrews Road - (SAR)",
             "St Annes-on-Sea - (SAS)",
             "St Austell - (SAU)",
             "St Bees - (SBS)",
             "St Budeaux Ferry Road - (SBF)",
             "St Budeaux Victoria Road - (SBV)",
             "St Columb Road - (SCR)",
             "St Denys - (SDN)",
             "St Erth - (SER)",
             "St Germans - (SGM)",
             "St Helens Central - (SNH)",
             "St Helens Junction - (SHJ)",
             "St Helier (Surrey) - (SIH)",


};
}
```

Comment: Why on earth would you do this like this? Instead put the data into a file and then read the file into your program.

Answer (score 1):

I presume that you have not pasted the full list, since you seem to missing stations starting with C-F!

The problem here is that you have coded up what is effectively one large code section.  The maximum size that a code section can be is 64 KB, which I suspect you have exceeded once the static data is placed into the compiled module. The cod creation process can't break this up and place this in multiple cod files (search for references to sibling cod files to understand this concept).  So you have two options:

1. Split it up yourself - for example have 26 different arrays each
   with a different starting letter
2. Load the array from a text file, there is no runtime size restriction and even though there is a maximum size of 64 KB for a resource in one cod file, I believe that resources can be split up.

**Update**

I have actually just tested this, and I can add a 2500 entry array, like the one supplied (in fact I just replicated the contents of the sample 3 times to get over 2500 entries), and it works fine (on a Simulator).  So I suspect another problem.  Can you try reducing the size of this array to confirm that the problem then disappears?  Also please tell us the OS you are building with and the OS on the target device.  Is it Simulator or actual device?